# How to disable word wrapping in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3, word-wrap

In *Sublime Text 2* there was a menu option to disable word wrapping, now it seems the word wrapping is forced without the ability to disable it.

[image: Sublime Text 3, wrap paragraph]

I've tried to set: `"word_wrap": false` in *User's Syntax Specific* settings, but this option takes no effect.

So how do I disable the word wrapping for the given file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### How do I disable the word wrapping for the given file?

> I've tried to set: `"word_wrap": false` in User's Syntax Specific settings, but this option takes no effect.

According to multiple online sources there should be a trailing comma `,` after false.

> ```
> "word_wrap": "false",
> ```

You can also set the wrap width to a large number:

> ```
> "wrap_width": 9999,
> ```

Source [SUBLIME TEXT 3 : how to disable word wrap in build output? - Technical Support - Sublime Forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-3-how-to-disable-word-wrap-in-build-output/9907/3)

And there is also `Word Wrap: Toggle` from the command palette:

> The `Word Wrap: Toggle` item from the Command Palette uses the
>   `toggle_setting` command. This sets the preference directly on the
>   view, which indeed overrides any default, user or syntax specific
>   preferences.
>
> You can return to the user/syntax specific settings behavior by
>   closing and reopening any files where the `Word Wrap: Toggle` item
>   from the Command Palette was used, as the view specific settings will
>   be lost when the file is closed. Alternatively, you could achieve the
>   same thing without closing any files by opening the ST Python console
>   (View menu -> Show Console) and typing
>   `view.settings().erase('word_wrap')` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will clear
>   the view-specific setting for the active tab.
>
> You could also get it to clear the setting from all open views in the
>   current window at once, using `[view.settings().erase('word_wrap') for
>   view in window.views()]` <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Source [Sublime Text: word wrap toggle from menu disabling syntax specific settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47551267/3536342), answer by [Keith Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4473405/keith-hall)

Comment: I think restarting the editor helped, as I was struggling to see the effect by using the same editor instance.

Comment: tnx bro! work fine here...